# How can I go about efficiently transforming an SQL log to a CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I have an SQL .log file that's around 5GB. It was provided by a client so I'd hate to ask them to export it for me in a different format. It has the following structure:

```
Header 1 Header 2 Header 3 Header 4
-------- -------- -------- --------
value a  value 1  value 2  value 3
value a  value 4  value 5  value 6
value b  value 7  value 8  value 9

Header 1 Header 2 Header 3 Header 4
-------- -------- -------- --------
value b  value 10  value 11  value 12
value b  value 13  value 14  value 15
value b  value 16  value 17  value 18
```

I've tried parsing it by converting it to a .txt reading each line separately, processing it then moving on to the next line by doing the following:

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Is there a way of converting a .log file to a pandas data frame directly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to be more specific about why your approach isn’t efficient eough. What have you tried - edit your code into the question.

Comment: Is this something you have to do one time, or repeatedly? Because ultimately, you're at best going to get a constant-time speedup, and how much effort do you want to put into shaving 70% of the time off a 5-minute process? (Especially  if you have to use tools you're not as familiar with and struggle with debugging code you don't understand as well…)

Comment: @barny trying to parse a 5GB file by loading it a line at a time is really time consuming

Comment: @abarnert only have to read the file once but currently it takes 5 hours to parse a fraction of it - it's a list of transactions and I'm grouping them by user ID.

Comment: @cyril No, it really isn't time-consuming. Python's file iterator actually buffers up decent-sized chunks and feeds out of the buffer, so it's not actually doing 100M reads. The overhead for looping 100M times in Python instead of in C is on the order of a second. Decoding 100M lines of Unicode text might add around 10 seconds, but if you don't need that part, you can just open the file in binary mode and process it as bytes. If your code is taking hours, the bottleneck is probably somewhere else.

Comment: @abarnert I'll look into it - thanks for the insight!

Comment: If you're storing the whole thing in memory, that could well be the issue. For example, 5GB of raw data could easily turn into, say, 25GB of Python objects, and if you've only got 16GB of available RAM, that will throw you into swap hell and make everything slow to a crawl. So, if you really need to hold everything, you may want to put it into a Pandas or Numpy collection (which should only take a bit over 5GB of RAM) even if you can't find a way to do it without iterating line by line.

Comment: Another possibility is that the actual parsing, grouping, etc. work you're doing really does take hours to run. If so, just using Pandas for looping but still doing the work itself the same way will only knock off a few seconds of time, but if you can rewrite the slow part of the work in terms of Pandas operations, that could knock off hours. But anyway, the first step is to try to get some profiling information (or at least out-of-line benchmarking simulations) to see what part you need to focus on.

Comment: For the example you have given, what does your expected output look like? Please add that to your question using the [edit] button.

Comment: @cyril trying to drag important information out of you is very time consuming. I’m not going to bother.

Comment: @barny no worries, thanks for your time